# R: Truncate string without splitting words

Tags: string, r

I have bunch of strings, some of which are fairly long, like so:

```
movie.titles <- c("Il divo: La spettacolare vita di Giulio Andreotti","Defiance","Coco Before Chanel","Happy-Go-Lucky","Up","The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus")
```

I would now like to truncate these strings to a maximum of, say, 30 characters, but in such a way that no words are split up in the process and ideally such that if the string is truncated ellipses are added to the end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an R-based solution:

```
trimTitles <- function(titles) {
    len <- nchar(titles)
    cuts <- sapply(gregexpr(" ", titles), function(X) {
            max(X[X<27])})
    titles[len>=27] <- paste0(substr(titles[len>=27], 0, cuts[len>=27]), "...")
    titles
}
trimTitles(movie.titles)
# [1] "Il divo: La spettacolare ..."  "Defiance"                     
# [3] "Coco Before Chanel"            "Happy-Go-Lucky"               
# [5] "Up"                            "The Imaginarium of Doctor ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at the `abbreviate` function. It abbreviates strings, and allows some control. See:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/abbreviate.html

For the man page.